# How to correctly use objects instead of multiple parameters?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, object

How to correctly use objects instead of multiple parameters in my case?

```
class Test{ 
async createUser(
    url: string,
    name: string,
    email: string,
    phone: string,
    street: string,
...
  ) {
    await Page.setUrl(url);
    await Page.setEmail(email);

 ...
   
  }
}
```

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI while I may agree, I'm not sure how this helps.

Comment: I hope as well!

Answer (score 1):

you can use an [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html)

```js
interface User {
  url: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  street: string;
}

class Test{ 
async createUser(user: User) {
    await Page.setUrl(user.url);
    await Page.setEmail(user.email);

 ...
   
  }
}
```

Comment: In TS, the `interface` keyword is always with a lowercase `i`

Answer (score -1):

use the concept of spread operators. Know more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

create an object variable like this:

```
result = { 
    url: string,
    name: string,
    email: string,
    phone: string,
    street: string,
}
```

and then pass it as a parameter like this

```
 async createUser (...result){
    //get variable you wan to use
    const {url, name, email} = result;
    //your code here
   }
```

Comment: Your createUser method signature has zero type safety and defeats the purpose of using Typescript.

Comment: yeah, I know that. but I think the question was all about the using of objects instead of multiple parameters

Comment: (1) orig `createUser` had a fixed set of strongly typed named params, but yours with its single rest param takes an unlimited number of `any` values.  (2) the destructuring of `result` is broken because you can't destructure a type `any[]` into named variables.

Comment: Yes, thanks I got it. Can you please correct this code, thanks in advance for that